# Comunicação Serial Java

Tags: java, linux, centos

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em Java que se comunica com microcontroladores através de portas seriais, nos testes realizados no Windows tudo ocorreu perfeitamente bem mas no Linux, mais precisamente no CentOS, a aplicação é abortada pela VM e exibe o seguinte erro:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff49482d733, pid=3441, tid=140688439260928

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_71-b14) (build 1.7.0_71-mockbuild_2014_10_17_22_23-b00)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
 Distribution: Built on CentOS release 6.5 (Final) (Fri Oct 17 22:23:16 UTC 2014)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [librxtxSerial.so+0x7733]  Java_gnu_io_RXTXPort_nativeDrain+0xc3
```

Já substituí as bibliotecas(estou usando RXTX) e o arquivo librxtxSerial.so por outros de versões diferentes e o problema persiste. Como posso resolver?